# How to print the tables in each link under a specific heading in selenium?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I would like to extract all the tables from all the links under a specific headline on a webpage.

The code should be able to go to a specific heading and load all the tables from all the links in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I misinterpreted what you wanted.. `.text` will get you the words inside the a tag. `<a href="http://url">this is what it would get</a>`.
If you wanted the actual link you were on the right track, but your elements were too broad.

Ok elaboration on this from what i've been talking about, there were a few things wrong with your code:

- You called a webdriver as `chrome` and then again as `browser`. You only need one of these.
- Your path has a bare `\` in it. all Windows paths should have `\\` instead of all backslashes.

Now your elems code.. you've listed a lot of things, you should get one group of elements per line and make your way through the page code with inspector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(
    'C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe',
    chrome_options=chrome_options)
browser.get(
    "https://www.juniper.net/support/eol/") # <-- Sample Website here
time.sleep(1)

# Get the ul linklist elements, and all the links in them.
# So you can see how you could use this to narrow it down further.

lists = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul.linkList") <-- Sample css_selector for the heading you want to extract from
links = [link.find_elements_by_tag_name("a") for link in lists]

# Now in links we have a list for each column element
# You can use indexing like links[0] to only select one column
for elems in links:
    print([link.get_attribute("href") for link in elems])
```

To navigate the links, you have to send the driver (you called it `browser`) to them.. I'd use a function for this if it gets more complicated, you can pass `browser` as a variable.

```
tables = []
for elems in links:
    tables += [link.get_attribute("href") for link in elems]


for link in tables:
    browser.get(link)
    table = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
    if table:
        table_rows = [t.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr") for t in table]
        for table_row in table_rows:
            your_result = [t.text for t in table_row if not t.startswith("Pages")]
            if your_result:
                print(your_result)

browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

Once you're in the process repeats.. inspect the page first. Get the elements you want with the same methods.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I get the error __'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'__

Comment: Hmm.. I wouldn't have expected that. It might have something to do with the wide variety of css selectors you're going for.. using the inspector in chrome or firefox I can see that all the links are just simple <a href=""> type links, so you should try to focus on just those. I'll have a look and try out your code.

Comment: I need to extract the tables in those links, so if you have another suggestion pelase tell me

Comment: basically I want to extract the tables in those links

Comment: I'm installing selenium in a virtualenv to see what's really happening.. but i'm not sure why you're getting every element you can as css selectors when you could use `elems = browser.find_elements_by_tag("a")` to get all the links on the page.

Comment: I am open for change as long as I can extract the table from all the links under that heading, thank you for installing it.

Comment: __browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")__ this extracts all links rather than the specific links under the heading

Comment: Yep sorry.. that was a typo. What do you mean by "the heading" ? Is "Hardware Technical Support Bulletin (TSB) Notifications" a heading you mean? From inspector I can see the only class involved in these links is `<ul class="linkList">`.. so i'd try to zero in on that. With Selenium you can get an element and then get the all the a elements from that element.. So you should narrow it down with a few lines instead of trying to do it all at once.

Comment: Ok I think I see what you wanna do now? Does the edit help you?

Comment: __NameError: name 'link' is not defined__ please double check. and yes thank you for pointing out the chrome error

Comment: It's working for me. If you're getting a NameError I would assume a typo in `for link in tables`

Comment: Also you've imported pandas.. I don't think you'll need it (unless you're using it for something else). When scraping web tables it will only complicate things. Usually you're looking for `td`, `th` and `tr` tags just like how you scraped the links.

Comment: I think the typpo is here__I think the typo was here:     links = [links.find_elements_by_tag_name("a") for links in lists]__

Comment: It ran like that for me, but yes it should've been `links = [link.find_elements_by_tag_name("a") for link in lists]`

Comment: also we are crawling the left side of the web, instead of the right side of the web. It reaches the end of the list and then says __ Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document__

Comment: Usually when you get that you should wait a sec and run it again. I don't know what you mean by "left side of the web". It will just get any `ul` elements of class `linklist` and getting all `a` elements `href` text from inside those elements.. i'm not sure if that's a perfect solution for you, it's just a demonstration of how to refine the elements on the page.

Comment: Also make sure you aren't running old variables you got from the first page after you move to one of the others.

Comment: And make sure you don't run `browser.close()` or `browser.quit()` (I think you only need one of these btw) before you run the loop.

Comment: that is because it reaches the end of the list and does not terminate then this error comes

Comment: I think I see the problem.. I put `for link in tables:` inside `for elems in links:`.. tables shouldn't be recreated once we're going into new links. See my edit.. I'm trying again.

Comment: actually ignore that error. But this iteration now prints the links :D It does not print the tables within those links which is the orginal question ! But I really appreciate everything you did so far !

Comment: so this worked great ! THank you, lets delete all the comments and clean it up so everyone can use it too ! :D

Comment: No worries, I edited it in a way to scrape those tables.. I'll be honest i'm like 7 beers deep and you could probably work on making the for loops and list comprehensions a little neater. But hey I hope it helps.. If it solves it for you accept the answer, otherwise an upvote never hurt :)

Comment: thank you for your time! I truly appreciate it! yes it did work, I accepted it as correct answer, and I will upvote it at reptution 15. Thanks again mate ! and enjoy your beers !